# Converting `flatMap` to `for-comprehension` with Either

Tags: scala

Given an `Either[String,Int]`:

```
scala> val z: Either[String, Int] = Right(100)
z: Either[String,Int] = Right(100)
```

I can write the following code with `flatMap`:

```
scala> z.right.flatMap(x => if(x == 100) Left("foo") else Right(x))
res14: scala.util.Either[String,Int] = Left(foo)
```

But, what am I doing wrong with the `for comprehension` version?

```
scala> for {
     |  a <- z.right
     |  _ <- if(a == 100) Left("foo") else Right(a)
     | } yield a
<console>:11: error: value map is not a member of Product with Serializable 
         with scala.util.Either[String,Int]
               _ <- if(a == 100) Left("foo") else Right(a)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(a == 100) Left("foo") else Right(a)` is an `Either[String, Int]`, and not a `LeftProjection` or `RightProjection`, so it doesn't have `map` or `flatMap`. You need to project it as well:

```
for {
    a <- z.right
    _ <- (if(a == 100) Left("foo") else Right(a)).right
} yield a
```

The difference between this and the one-liner is that the one-liner is equivalent to:

```
for {
    a <- z.right
} yield (if(a == 100) Left("foo") else Right(a))
```

.. Which does not have an extra `map` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I think the accepted answer for this question is obsolete now.

since scala `2.12`, `Either` is right biased by default.
So the `Either` has `map` and `flatMap` defined.

```
/** Binds the given function across `Left`.
 *
 *  {{{
 *  Left(12).left.flatMap(x => Left("scala")) // Left("scala")
 *  Right(12).left.flatMap(x => Left("scala")) // Right(12)
 *  }}}
 *  @param f The function to bind across `Left`.
 */
def flatMap[A1, B1 >: B](f: A => Either[A1, B1]): Either[A1, B1] = e match {
  case Left(a) => f(a)
  case _       => e.asInstanceOf[Either[A1, B1]]
}

/** Maps the function argument through `Left`.
 *
 *  {{{
 *  Left(12).left.map(_ + 2) // Left(14)
 *  Right[Int, Int](12).left.map(_ + 2) // Right(12)
 *  }}}
 */
def map[A1](f: A => A1): Either[A1, B] = e match {
  case Left(a) => Left(f(a))
  case _       => e.asInstanceOf[Either[A1, B]]
}
```

Therefore you don't have to use `RightProjection` since `Either` is right biased by default. So the following code works.

```
  val z: Either[String, Int] = Right(100)

  val ans = for {
    a <- z
    _ <- if (a == 100) Left("foo") else Right(a)
  } yield a
```

Hope this helps.